# Why i get this message when i try to open phpMyAdmin in Wamp2.0 "You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server."

Tags: permissions, wamp, wampserver

i already read some post and solution that i read. They said i need to edit my c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf..
i try many solution like :

```
 1. <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

 2. AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Al
Allow from all

 3. Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

i've try all of them, but still i can't open my phpMyAdmin.hope someone can explain and help me..Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your "/phpmyadmin" Alias is either not set up properly, or is pointing to a Directory that has no permissions set (in config) or wrong permissions set.
2. Or you might have an .htaccess file specifically blocking access, though it doesn't sound like it.

You should either reinstall your flavor of wamp (whichever distro you use), or try any number of other WAMPs that come with phpMyAdmin set up and ready to run...

[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), [UniformServer](http://www.uniformserver.com/), [Wamp-Developer](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper) (commercial), Xampp, and half-a-dozen others...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

Comment: i want to create a database and use it for my website . i'm quiet new in WAMP, so i don't know which suit for me ..
is there any other solution than reinstall/installing others wamp?

Comment: i've reinstall my WAMP 2.0 so many times,also i already try to use WAMP 2.2 but i still can't access my phpMyAdmin

Comment: @EzwanAbid, it kind of sounds like something is messed up on your wamp because /phpmyadmin should work from the get-go, so unless you want to spend time debugging this issue, the quickest thing you can do is uninstall/reinstall. Also make sure you are restarting Apache after config changes! And also on re-install, make sure to delete the WAMP folder.

Comment: i always restarting my Apache after make a changes on Alias..all kind of solution i've tried,reinstall about 4-7 times already..and i almost become crazy facing this problem.

Comment: ok i just reinstall my Wamp2.0 ...and i receive this error message "#2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)"

Comment: @EzwanAbid, either MySQL has not been started, can't start, or phpmyadmin's config is messed up. If you're having so many issues with this one WAMP distro, maybe try another WAMP distro?

Comment: WAMP distro? example? maybee u can suggest to me 1.

Comment: @EzwanAbid, "distro" -> distribution A.K.A. package. A good place to start is in the above wikipedia page that lists a bunch of them.